# how to pass a method call to JOptionPane.showMessageDialog parameter

Tags: java, joptionpane

I have a class called Person and within it there's a method to show the details of a person

```
public class Person 
{
private int age = 12;
private double salary=12000;
public void show() {

    System.out.println("Age : " + age);
    System.out.println("Salary: "+ salary);
}
```

In another `class Test`, i would like to display the Person's details using the **show()** method  from `Person Class` via the `showMessageDialog`

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Test
{
public static void main(String[] args){
Person s = new Person();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s.show(), "Person Info", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}
```

The end goal is to display a person info on Joptionpane message box
**I am wondering if it can be achieved **without altering the show()** method

But the code failed to compile

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method showMessageDialog(Component, Object, String, int) in the type JOptionPane is not applicable for the arguments (null, void, String, int)*

Anyone have any idea would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

`Person.show()` is returning `void`. So, you are getting this error.

`showMessageDialog(Component, **Object**, String, int)` 
`(null, **void**, String, int)`

You can return String from `show()`

```
public String show() {
   return "Age : " + age + " Salary: "+ salary;
}
```

Or define a `toString()` method.

```
public String toString() {
       return "Age : " + age + " Salary: "+ salary;
}
```

And then show by following

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, s.toString(), "Person Info", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

Or you can just show Dialog from show method.

```
public void show() {
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Age : " + age + " Salary: "+ salary, "Person Info", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: @ Khushit Shahthanks for your information. I am wondering if it is possible to achieve the same result without altering the show() method

Comment: Then you should create a toString() method

Comment: @epiphany Edited Answer